# AngularJS: How to pass data from view to controller in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, view, controller

I'm developing an application which adds/edits/removes contacts.
Here is how my adding contact view template looks like:

```html
<input placeholder="name" ng-model="contact.name" type="text">
<input placeholder="number" ng-model="contact.number" type="text">
<a href="#/"><button>Add</button></a>
```

And here is my controllers file, the controller used for adding is the last one:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']).config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/contact/:index', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/edit.html',
        controller: 'Edit'
    }).when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/contacts.html'
    }).when('/add', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/add.html',
        controller: 'Add'
    })
    .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
}).controller('Contacts',  ['$scope',function($scope){
    $scope.contacts = [
    {name:'Hazem', number:'01091703638'},
    {name:'Taha', number:'01095036355'},
    {name:'Adora', number:'01009852281'},
    {name:'Esmail', number:'0109846328'}
    ];
}]).controller('Edit', ['$scope','$routeParams',function($scope,$routeParams){
    $scope.contact = $scope.contacts[$routeParams.index];
    $scope.index = $routeParams.index;
}]).controller('Add', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.contacts.push({name: contact.name, number: contact.number});
}]);
```

I've got an error in the chrome inspector says:
    ReferenceError: contactname is not defined

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
controller('Add', function(){
    this.contacts.push({name: contactname, number: contactnumber});
}]);
```

Each controller has its own scope, in your Add controller you are simply trying to push something that isn't defined into a variable that's also undefined `$scope.contacts`.

Also on your view, when you pass something into ng-model, this is basically creating a two-way data binding between a variable with that name in your controller. So in this case, your html will create two variables: `$scope.contactname` and `$scope.contactnumber`.

On your view you are also calling a function Add() which hasn't been defined on your controller.

Below is what your controller should look like:

```
controller('Add', function(){
   var vm = this;
   vm.contacts = []; //you declare your array of contacts in the controllers scope
   //vm.contacts = getContactsFromDB(); //typically you'd be getting your initial list from a DB

   //As good practice, you should initialize the objects in your scope:
   vm.contactname = '';
   vm.contactnumber = '';

   vm.Add = function() {
     vm.contacts.push({name: vm.contactname, number: vm.contactnumber});
     //Also you could add the data to a database
     /*
       ContactService
       .AddNewContact(vm.contactname, vm.contactnumber)
       .then(function(){
              vm.contacts.push(
                  {name: vm.contactname, number: vm.contactnumber});
       });
     */

     //Finally you should reset the form variables
     vm.contactname = '';
     vm.contactnumber = '';
   }  


}]);
```

Comment: Thanks!! this worked for me
Here is how I modified the controller.. the add function fixed the issue

controller('Add', ['$scope', function($scope){
 $scope.add= function() {
  $scope.contacts.push({name: $scope.contactname, number: $scope.contactnumber});
 }
}]);

and modifying the add button in the view:

    <input placeholder="name" ng-model="contactname" type="text">
    <input placeholder="number" ng-model="contactnumber" type="text">
    <a href="#/"><button ng-click="add()">Add</button></a>

Answer (score 7):

Please see below

use `<button ng-click="Add()">Add</button>` instaed of `<a>` tag

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('Add', ['$scope', function($scope){
  $scope.contacts = [];
  $scope.Add = function() {
    $scope.contacts.push({name: $scope.contactname, number: $scope.contactnumber});
    }
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="Add">
<input placeholder="name" ng-model="contactname" type="text">
<input placeholder="number" ng-model="contactnumber" type="text">
<button ng-click="Add()">Add</button>
 
    <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="con in contacts">{{con.name}} {{con.number}}</li>
    </ul>
    
    </div>
  </div>
```

In your Add controller 
change

```
.controller('Add', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.contacts.push({name: contactname, number: contactnumber});
}]);

.controller('Add', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.contacts.push({name: $scope.contactname, number: $scope.contactnumber});
}]);
```