# How to pass data from controller to view in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, view, controller

I know how to pass data from view to controller Here is the [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26013535/angularjs-how-to-pass-data-from-view-to-controller-in-angularjs) I want to pass data from controller to view  in angular-js. Is it possible if so,How it works?

Comment: Do you know how the `$scope` works?

Comment: Is this thread alive?

Answer (score 4):

```
angular.module('yourApp').controller('Contacts',  ['$scope',function($scope){
    $scope.contacts = [
    {name:'Hazem', number:'01091703638'},
    {name:'Taha', number:'01095036355'},
    {name:'Adora', number:'01009852281'},
    {name:'Esmail', number:'0109846328'}
    ];
}])
```

In the above code "contacts" will be passed to the view. It will then be available within the controlled element like so:

```
<div ng-controller="Contacts">{{contacts[0].name}}</div>
```

So we defined the controller we want to use, then we can access the $scope object it passed to the view. You can add as many items to the $scope as you want, an example below:

```
angular.module('yourApp').controller('Contacts',  ['$scope',function($scope){
    $scope.contacts = [
    {name:'Hazem', number:'01091703638'},
    {name:'Taha', number:'01095036355'},
    {name:'Adora', number:'01009852281'},
    {name:'Esmail', number:'0109846328'}
    ];
    $scope.rabbit = "Rabbit";
}])
```